# How much energy released by the Theia-Gaia impact?

Tags: earth-history, moon, earth-system

I read somewhere that the Chicxulub impact released the energy equivalent of anywhere from 100-300 teratons of TNT. That's an impressive amount of energy.

Assuming a head on collision (according to [newer research](http://newsroom.ucla.edu/releases/moon-was-produced-by-a-head-on-collision-between-earth-and-a-forming-planet)), how would it compare to the impact that created our moon?

Comment: It would be insignificant in comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty estimate.
The [gravitational self-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy) of a uniform-density sphere is
$$
U = \frac35 \frac{GM^2}R
$$ 
Let's assume Theia had the same mass and density as Mars, and that Gaia contained the rest of the mass of the Earth-Moon system.
The binding energies for the four bodies are then

```
theia/mars 4.82e+30 joules
gaia       1.90e+32 joules
earth      2.24e+32 joules
moon       1.24e+29 joules
```

You can see that Theia and the Moon contribute to the binding energy starting the third significant figure: moving the 90% of Theia's mass to Gaia, leaving us with the Earth and the Moon, must have released something like $0.3\times10^{32}\rm\,J$ of gravitational binding energy as heat.

Kinetic energies due to Earth's rotation and the Moon's orbit are irrelevant compared to Earth's binding energy --- the biggest contributor there is $0.25\times10^{30}\rm\,J$ associated with Earth's daily rotation.
It's probably safe to assume the same about the progenitors.

Apparently a [teraton of TNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent) is $4\times10^{21}\rm\,J$, if you insist on that comparison.

Note that I've assumed nothing about the geometry of the collision, whether it was head-on or glancing. I'm only making assumptions about the (well-known) final state and the (poorly constrained) initial state.

Comment: That's about 10 zettatons of TNT.